# How can i read data on server send with headers in node

Tags: ajax, node.js

I am trying to send data with ajax like this:

```
        xhttp.open("post", "addTeam", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send("tName=" + tName);
```

And how can i get it on server, i try to do this like this:

```
var tournamentName = req.headers.tName;
```

or `var tournamentName = req.headers;`
but i cannot see it, have you got any ideas, thanks for answear
I also say that i use bodyParser

Comment: When doing a POST request, you'll need a [bodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) or to write your own parser, the data isn't magically available in `req.headers`

Comment: I am using bodyParser so that is not it

Comment: Well, then it's `req.body.tName` to access the values

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
var tournamentName = req.query.tName
```

Also, take a look here : [request query](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)